# Count and select distinct date format type from table column

Tags: mysql, sql

In my table, I have multiple types of date format in table column for e.g.

```
20 May 1984
20.03.2004
20/June/2005
20 August 1925
```

So how to get distinct date formats which are used on my table.

Output should be like this:-

```
column | count
-------|------------
 d M y |   15
 d.m.y |   25
 d/M/y |   12
 d F y |   10
```

Comment: To clarify, any and all of the above formats can occur in a single field?

Comment: @toonice this is an old table and don't have any specific date format that's why it have multiple date format

Comment: may i know data type of this field ?

Comment: @Paramjeet hope your data type for this above column is varchar ?

Comment: @AhmedGinani varchar

Comment: @BunkerBoy Yes, it is varchar

Comment: Is `2017-05-03` a possible format?

Comment: Is `03-05-17` a possible format?

Comment: Is `May 03, 2017` a possible format?

Comment: @toonice I didn't understand exactly what's your point

Comment: They are all the same date.  The first format is the ISO / Japanese format of `yyyy-mm-dd`, the second is the old-style `dd-mm-yy` and the last one is the American format of `mmm dd, yyyy`.  All of the values you have supplied have been in a `day-month-year` structure (with various separators).  If that structure is consistent for all of your values, then we can convert easily enough, but if the other formats are also possible, then things become *much* more complicated.

Comment: @Paramjeet - Your requirement is to get count of same date ? e.g `DISTINCT(datefield)`

Comment: @toonice, Ahmed Ginani I only want to select what all date format my column have distinctly.

Comment: IMHO - This is actually impossible! Can you tell the difference between 01-02-2015 and 01-02-2015?  But is the 1st Feb 2015 really the same as the 2nd Jan 2015.  Some dates are indistinguishable.

Comment: Paramjeet, Not all dates have an obvious format.  For example `02-01-09` can mean `02 January 2009`, `01 February 2009`, `09 January 2002`, etc., depending on what format they are presented in.  If all formats are possible with your data, then your problem can not be solved.  How ever if *all* the dates are at least `day-month-year` in structure, and the year is always four digits, then we *can* safely convert them.  Thus I ask, is the structure always going to be `day-month-year`?

Comment: @Paramjeet try combine substring index with (. space /) and regular expression and find pattern like [0-9] [char] [0-9][count]

Comment: @Paramjeet please update your question with desired output, i m little bit confused

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to solve this. `STR_TO_DATE` gives `NULL` if the value could not read in the specified format. So with `SUM` and `CASE WHEN` you can count the found dates with specified format:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN NOT STR_TO_DATE(colVal, '%d %M %Y') IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'd M y',
    SUM(CASE WHEN NOT STR_TO_DATE(colVal, '%d.%m.%Y') IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'd.m.y',
    SUM(CASE WHEN NOT STR_TO_DATE(colVal, '%d/%M/%Y') IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'd/M/y'
FROM table_name
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc0e9/2/0

You can add more such rules with `STR_TO_DATE` like the above example. You can find an overview with all format specifier on MySQL here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

> **Note:** There is no detection for date formats in MySQL, so you have to review the values on your column to get all possible date formats.

Comment: Your answer is for the specific condition.My table is too long. If I don't know what all date format is in the table. In that condition what will I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like as below:

```
SELECT 

    IF( cdate REGEXP (' ') , 'd M Y' , 
       IF(cdate REGEXP ('.') , 'd.m.Y' ,
          IF(cdate REGEXP ('/') , 'd/M/Y' ,'1')
       )
    ) AS format_type  , count(id) as total 


FROM datawithdate GROUP BY format_type
```

Here `cdate` is your column name and `datawithdate` is table name. you can replace with your original and try it

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50809/1

*Note: I've put 1 in else condition but you can use more if you want*

Comment: Your answer is for the specific condition.My table is too long. If I don't know what all date format is in the table. In that condition what will I do?

Comment: First of all you have to find all date format. you can find using this:

`SELECT datefield` from table GROUP by datefield` 

this query will provide you all unique date format date. which will help to see how many date formate are available in your table